# get list of object from array of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

It is a simple javascript problem and i am unable to get my head through it

```
const jsObjects = [
      {a: 1, b: 2}, 
      {a: 3, b: 4}, 
      {a: 5, b: 6}, 
      {a: 7, b: 8}
    ]


let result = jsObjects.find(obj => {
  return obj.b === 6
})

console.log(result)
```

i just want to console the entire list of 'b' rather than find a single variable 'b' which holds value 6

is there any way to do that

Comment: `jsObjects.filter(obj => obj.b === 6);`

Comment: `let out = jsObjects.map(e => e.b)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of `Array.find()`

```js
const jsObjects = [
      {a: 1, b: 2}, 
      {a: 3, b: 4}, 
      {a: 5, b: 6}, 
      {a: 7, b: 8}
    ]
    
    
let result = jsObjects.filter(obj => obj.b === 6)

console.log(result)
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to take only one property, then you can use `Array.map()`

```js
const jsObjects = [
      {a: 1, b: 2}, 
      {a: 3, b: 4}, 
      {a: 5, b: 6}, 
      {a: 7, b: 8}
    ]
    
    
let result = jsObjects.map(obj => obj.b)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: i need the output like this: 
{b: 2, b:4, b:6, b:8}
how can i get this?

Comment: Your desired output is not a valid object structure as it holds different values for same key. If you need to get them as array, please see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

If you still want them as objects in an array, you can update Harun's code like this:

````
let myBs = [];
let result = jsObjects.map(obj => myBs.push({b: obj.b}));

console.log(myBs);```
````